# I have the problem in url path settings?

Tags: uri, path-aliases

I have  some basic pages in my site, it has url paths.

When i pass the url its works properly.

Eg:

www.mysite.com/about-us it opens perfectly. But my problem is if i pass url as  www.mysite.com/about-us/sgajfsaff(something rondomly) it will also opens the about-us page not goto 404 page.

Is there any solution to redirect it 404 page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any module like pathauto?

Comment: That is the normal behavior of Drupal.

Comment: [Need to redirect the non-existence URL's to 404 page instead of parent url](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156234/need-to-redirect-the-non-existence-urls-to-404-page-instead-of-parent-url)

Comment: But the administration menu bar not showing in the top page... Any help